# Sum with conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum, subquery, case

I have a table with three cloumns (tipo,ok,ko). I am trying to find a way to sum values based on conditions usint T-sql for example on the below table

| Tipo | KO | OK | Totale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| act-act | 28 | 477 | 505 |
| disktier | 15 | 7665 | Null |
| scopertura | 105 | 475 | 580 |
| Silver100% | 21 | 3141 | 3162 |
| Silverless50% | 82 | 7665 | Null |
| Silvermore50% | 130 | 7665 | Null |
| tra 2 siti | 65 | 7665 | Null |

for each row i am trying to put the sum of the Ko + ok as totale but for sum rows i want to put a mutual total thus for the null values i want to sum all their ko's to the mutual ok so at the end i need to have 7,957 for all the 4 null values thus ko1(15) + ko2(82) +ko3(130) +ko4(65) + mutual ok (7665) so the desired result should look like the below table,

| Tipo | KO | OK | Totale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| act-act | 28 | 477 | 505 |
| disktier | 15 | 7665 | 7957 |
| scopertura | 105 | 475 | 580 |
| Silver100% | 21 | 3141 | 3162 |
| Silverless50% | 82 | 7665 | 7957 |
| Silvermore50% | 130 | 7665 | 7957 |
| tra 2 siti | 65 | 7665 | 7957 |

here is the code that i'm using but its just sums the two columns for the first case i need to modify it to obtain the second case and obtain the desired result on the second table

```
select TIPO, KO, OK,
       sum(case when tipo in('act-act','scopertura','Silver100%') then (ko+ok)
                else null
           end ) as totale
From table
group by tipo , ok , ko
```

Comment: First of all with `tsql` (ie MS SQL Server) you cannot do `SELECT cola, colb, SUM(...)` without a `GROUP BY`, so I'm wondering how that query even executes ...

Comment: Since the sum is on the last column (totale) Obviously we need to group by the first three columns (tipo,ko,ok)

Comment: Yeah I know that, yet your query doesn't contain any group by. And to prevent misunderstandings you should always provide the code you are using right now. If you show some code that has obvious sytax errors, you will only get answers about that syntax errors ... and not about your actual problem ...

Comment: And is it guaranteed that all rows where the `totale` is shown als `null` will have the same value for `OK`? If not, what should happen if there are two or more different values for `OK` in those rows?

Comment: It’s guaranteed that the ok will always be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to compute the overall count rather than a subquery - hence avoiding an additional (and unnecessary) table scan:

```
select t.*,
    case 
        when tipo in ('act-act','scopertura','Silver100%') 
            then ko + ok 
            else ok + sum(case when tipo not in ('act-act','scopertura','Silver100%') then ko else 0 end) over() 
    end totale
from mytable t
```

The `sum(...) over()` expression does the window sum of `ko`s of the given `tipo` over the whole table.

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you can set a flag on `tipo` in a subquery first, then use it in the outer query:

```
select t.*,
    case 
        when flag_tipo = 1 
            then ko + ok 
            else ok + sum(case when flag_tipo = 0 then ko else 0 end) over() 
    end totale
from (
    select t.*, 
        case when tipo in ('act-act','scopertura','Silver100%') then 1 else 0 end as tipo_flag
    from mytable t  
) t
```

Comment: Well thanks yeah that’s much better now I don’t have to repeat the table two times

Answer (score 2):

For instance straightforward  like the following

```
-- get the sum of all ko values in the rows for types other then the defined
declare @kosum integer = (select sum(ko) from thetable where tipo not in ('act-act','scopertura','Silver100%'));

-- for each row either add ok + ko for the defined types
-- or add the ok (which will be the same) and the above sum for all other types
select 
    tipo, 
    ok, 
    ko, 
    case 
      when type in ('act-act','scopertura','Silver100%') then ko + ok 
      else @kosum +ok 
    end as totale
from thetable
```

If you want that all in one query, you can also replace the `@kosum` in the second query with the query calculating the variable. But I personally find it more readable with the variable

```
select 
    tipo, 
    ok, 
    ko, 
    case 
      when tipo in ('act-act','scopertura','Silver100%') then ko + ok 
      else ok + (select sum(ko) from thetable where tipo not in ('act-act','scopertura','Silver100%'))
    end as totale
from thetable
```

Comment: Well thanks that worked just fine my problem is that my table is consisted of alot of subquerries do i have to repeat it two times( one time when declaring the variable and the second one on the final select statement) or there is a way to go around that

Comment: No either you use the approach in the first code block (ie declaring the variable) and then refer to that variable in your final select. Or you use the second approach without declaring the variable and use the subquery directly ...